# Owl carousel infinite loop

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

What i am trying to achieve is to make my owl carousel infinite loop. after the last image slider revert to first image from right to left but i want my images not to revert back it mean after last image the first image will be came from left to right.

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('.five').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
autoPlay:true,
nav:true,
rewindNav:false,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:4
    }
}
  })
    });
```

Comment: loop: false,responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:4
    },
   1001:{
       items : 1
   }
}

Comment: tried but nothing happened.

Comment: What a version that you'r using?

Comment: owl carousel 2 and here is codepen link you can check https://codepen.io/amitwa/pen/rpMrrX

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use responsive class it always overwrite the top options.
So all you need is to add `loop` option to your responsive items.

```
responsive:{
  0:{
    items:1,
    loop:true
  },
  600:{
    items:3,
    loop:true
  },
  1000:{
    items:4,
    loop:true
  }
}
```

Comment: its Work for me